# OpenGL jpg image loaded with SOIL is displayed slanted

Tags: c++, opengl, soil

When loading the jpg image using SOIL, the image is displayed slanted and the colors are not right (i don't know how to describe it, because it is in color, but it looks black and white)

The intended version

[image: expectations]

However, it is displayed like this

[image: reality]

The shaders are:

vertex shader

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;
out vec3 ourColor;
out vec2 TexCoord;
void main(){
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0f);
    ourColor = color;
    TexCoord = texCoord;
}
```

fragment shader

```
#version 330 core
in vec3 ourColor;
in vec2 TexCoord;
out vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D ourTexture;
void main(){
    color = texture(ourTexture, TexCoord);
}
```

How to display it correctly, the intended way?

Comment: Is your image not a multiple of 4 pixels wide, by any chance? Does it work if it is?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the shader code. But set `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)` before `glTexImage2D`

Comment: @Rabbid76 It worked, thanks!

Comment: [Same problem over there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45486668/3233393).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default OpenGL assumes that the start of each row of an image is aligned with 4 bytes. This is because the [`GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml) parameter by default is 4. If the format of the image is RGB and *width*3* is not divisibly by 4, you must change the parameter before specifying the two-dimensional texture image (`glTexImage2D`):

```cpp
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
```